# Why can't I use a wildcard * on Access-Control-Allow-Headers when Allow-Credentials is set to true?

Tags: firefox, cors

I have a website where the React frontend resides in (let's say) app.mydomain.com and the api on api.mydomain.com.

The user submits a login request to the API and, upon logging in successfully, receives a nice cookie to be used later. The front-end talks only and directly to the API so the domain on the cookie is simply set to api.mydomain.com.

I use Axios to perform the requests with the `withCredentials` flag set to true, in order to receive the cookie.

The headers on the server to allow CORS are as follows:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://app.mydomain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

In this situation this is the response from Firefox:

[image: Firefox error when allow-headers is set to wildcard]

But, as soon as the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` value is set more specifically, say to
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept`, everything works.

[Mozilla says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials) they do not allow "wildcarding" the Origin value, not the Headers one, same [in this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#requests_with_credentials), where nothing is mentioned.

Why is Firefox behaving like this and why is it not mentioned anywhere that I can find?

Comment: Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers `*` is only allowed for requests _without_ credentials. Have you found Firefox is behaving differently to other browsers here?

Comment: The page you cited does answer my question. At the same time, I was expecting more clarity on Firefox part: as of now it just warns if Allow-Origin is set to '*' when credentials are enabled, but nothing particularly clear is said by the browser regarding headers settings

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards has been updated to include info on the restriction against using the `*` wildcard in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header in responses to credentialed requests. So thanks much —  because you made three good things happen: (1) you raised this question here and cited that MDN doc, (2) you got the attention of an SO contributor who took time to write up a high-quality answer, and (3) that led to the deficiency in the MDN doc being recognized by an MDN contributor, who got motivated enough to update it.

Comment: One request: Going forward, any time you run into problems/shortcomings with content in MDN articles, please consider raising issues at https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/new/choose. You can even consider directly updating the content yourself (e.g., at https://github.com/mdn/content/edit/main/files/en-us/web/http/cors/index.md) and following the guidance at https://github.com/mdn/content#simple-changes to submit pull requests. All the MDN sources are in GitHub & many of the sources are in Markdown (and all will be eventually), so it’s roughly as easy as writing a good Stack Overflow answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a preflight response that includes `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, an asterisk used as the value of header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is interpreted literally, not as a wildcard (i.e. "all headers allowed").

<s>It's true that the main [MDN page about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) doesn't explicitly state this rule.</s> However, the more specific [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#directives) about the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header does so explicitly:

> The value "`*`" only counts as a special wildcard value for requests without credentials (requests without HTTP cookies or HTTP authentication information). In requests with credentials, it is treated as the literal header name "`*`" without special semantics. Note that the `Authorization` header can't be wildcarded and always needs to be listed explicitly.

Edit (2023): As [sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker) pointed out in [his comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793536/why-cant-i-use-a-wildcard-on-access-control-allow-headers-when-allow-credenti/68799055#comment121638220_68793536), the [MDN Web Docs page about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) has since been updated and now states the following:

> When responding to a credentialed request: [...]
>
> - The server **must not** specify the "`*`" wildcard for the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response-header value, but must instead specify an explicit list of header names; for example, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type`

Here are clarifying quotes from the more authoritative [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax):

> For `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response headers, the value `*` counts as a wildcard **for requests without credentials**.
>
> `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response headers can only use `*` as value **when request’s credentials mode is not "`include`"**.

(my emphasis)

---

The relevant normative requirement for browsers that the spec states is in the **main fetch** algorithm at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#main-fetch, in step 13, substep 2:

> If *request*'s [credentials mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode) is not
> "`include`" and *headerNames* contains `*`, then set *response*’s [CORS-exposed header-name list](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-cors-exposed-header-name-list) to all unique [header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header) [names](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-name) in *response*’s [header list](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-header-list).

In other words, the browser behavior that spec statement requires for `*` is:

- if the credentials mode *is not* "`include`", the browser is required to examine the actual list of response headers in the response, and allow all of them
- if the credentials mode *is* "`include`", the browser is required to only allow any response header with the literal name "`*`"

At the end of that step, there’s actually a note saying pretty much the same thing:

> One of the *headerNames* can still be `*` at this point, but will only match a header whose name is `*`.